# Training NN with big numbers

Tags: optimization, networking, audio, loss

I am trying to train a NN to predict the frequency of a specific formant from a group of frequency bins, and the numbers I have both for the input and the output are in their hundreds. Should I rescale those numbers or is there an optimizer and loss function which is suitable for that task? BTW, I'm working with pytorch.

I have tried several loss functions and they soon accumulate to infinity. I have just tried SGD for an optimizer.